# I want to mask android.hardware.camera view in circle form with the help of Opengl, How I can do it?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, android-hardware, camera-view

I want to mask android.hardware.camera view in circle form with the help of Opengl, How I can do it?
Try to resolve it with https://github.com/google/grafika

But not understand how to convert Triangle in circle.

Comment: triangle? what triangle are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about Triangle_Fan.

Comment: it didnt improve your question in ant way...

Comment: Want to convert camera view in circle and other part become trance parent.

Comment: "become trance parent." ? ? ? you mean "become transparent." ?

Comment: yes, sorry for mistake .